# update a web project by changing single aspx.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, iis

I have to fix a legacy web service project created in C# and asp.net. It is not possible to open the project in visual studio as source safe errors and other missing libraries cause too many compile errors. I am not that familiar with web applications in .NET.

Is it possible to update a single aspx.cs file in the website directory which has a connection string hard coded that needs to be updated. If so, how is this eventually compiled and updated in IIS?

Comment: ASP.NET does not work that way as HTML. But as long as the application is out there running, it is **super easy** to get its code/dependencies out, so I won't say "not possible". So to answer your own question, you do need to spend time learning .NET, or hire someone with that experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've deployed to IIS, you cannot update the .cs file in ASP.net application as they are already compiled into .dll files in the bin folder. The files you can update are with extensions like .aspx .ascx and .config etc. You should modify the .cs file, compile and publish the dll into the bin folder.